# How to avoid making dependencies available for all packages in the module?

Tags: go, dependencies, project-structure

Coming form a .NET background, I am currently trying to adjust my first go project to a more go-typical project structure (similar to [this](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout)). The thing I don't understand is, how to avoid dependencies accidentally creeping into packages where they do not belong.

Suppose I have a project consisting of two parts, an app called `foo` and a model.

- my model has very few dependencies
- the `foo` app might have dependencies to libraries for http, logging, metrics, etc.

The project might look like this:

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── model
│   ├── person.go
│   └── address.go
├── cmd
│   └── runfoo
│       └── main.go
└── foolib
    └── applicationlogic.go
```

But because the module file is at the root, `go get github.com/httplib` will make `httplib` available also for the model. This approach has drawbacks:

- It is very easy (especially with VSCode auto-import and the like) and sometimes tempting to require `httplib` in the model, even though it does definitively not belong there.
- Looking at the `go.mod`, I can not determine which dependencies are for the model and which are for the app.

Now, I could use very fine-grained modules and add a `go.work` file for developing, but that feels like it will be hard to maintain (and is not aligned with the reference structure).

**How can I avoid making dependencies available for all packages and is it advisable to do so?**

Comment: Your [reference projecy  layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) is flawed. "The README makes clear that this is not official, but even the claim "it is a set of common historical and emerging project layout patterns in the Go ecosystem" is not accurate." [this is not a standard Go project layout #117](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout/issues/117)

Comment: @rocka2q thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question accordingly. I think the actual layout is not so important for the question, as long as you have multiple packages inside a module. Maybe I should have written that differently.

Comment: It might be possible to assert a certain dependency structure with tests (e.g. using https://github.com/fdaines/arch-go). It is a (somewhat) popular approach in other languages. But I have not tried it in go, so I cannot say anything about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I avoid making dependencies available for all packages [?]

You cannot (with one module).

> [...] and is it advisable to do so?

No, absolutely not.

The "drawbacks" you see aren't problematic at all and do not lead to any issues in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) 
I am not fully convinced that it is really a non-issue. From experience I know that it is always tempting to use 'what's there', leading to deeply-integrated, hard-to-remove dependencies which should not have been there in the first place. But might be that go handles this better than the languages I used so far.

Anyway, scattering the code across modules is probably much worse.

Comment: @user4758246 A package from the same module is not a "dependency" in the normal sense of the word.